# How to dynamically select last 5 list elements of an unordered list?

Tags: javascript

Using javascript, how do I select the last 5 list elements in an unordered list made with HTML?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Please do not ask us to write your code for you.

Comment: It's just a simple for loop, is it that hard to help someone out with a loop?

Comment: no it's not hard, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If it is so simple just do it?

Comment: share your code

Comment: If it's a **simple** for loop, surely you would be able to write it yourself. If you don't know how to do one specific part of it, perhaps you should tell us what that part is so we aren't forced to guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css selector

```
element.querySelectorAll(":nth-last-child(-n+5)")
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I try var items = ul.querySelectorAll(":nth-last(-n+5)") i get "items undefined"

Comment: Try using it like this [link](https://jsbin.com/zipocewedo/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var list = document.querySelector('ul');
  var children = list.children;
  var len = children.length;
  for(var i = len; i >= len-5; i--){
    children[i-1].style.color = "red";
  }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
<ul>
```